# Ajax : echo an array & fill textboxes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My goal is to fill several "input textboxes" with some ajax. For now, I managed to fill a single textbox this way :

```
document.getElementById("meow").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

And here is my php script which returns the mysql results, by "echoing" it :

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE auth = '".$q."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {echo $row['prenom'].$row['nom'];}
```

My question is : can I echo an entire array (or some kind of special character string) from my php script, and then parsing it with ajax, so I can fill the textboxes with appropriate data (I already tried several ways, like Json.parse, but it doesn't work, or maybe I'm doing it wrong) ? Thanks for helping !

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: Do you need any specific part of my code ? (But all the important things are already here, everything else in my code is "classic"...)

Comment: please do some research on `jquery` and `JSON`, it's better to send your data in a well formatted structure from your `PHP` to your `ajax`. so it's better to use some formats like `JSON`. and using `jquery` will help you to process the returned data with ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I managed like this : I put a separator between each data taken from the database, like so :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {echo $row['prenom'].";".$row['nom'];}
```

And on the other side, I parse the data, and I put it in the right textbox, this way :

```
var res = xmlhttp.responseText.split(";"); 
document.getElementById("meow").value=res[1];
```